# React - styled components get class name

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, styled-components

I looked on the Internet but did not find a suitable example, is it possible to get the class name and interact with it using styled components, for example

```
const Example = styled.(And here get the class name and not the tag, "Home")`
  color: green;
`;

<p className={"Home"}>Overview</p>
```

I understand that the example I wrote looks stupid, I just want to show with this example what I want

I will now describe my problem in more detail. I have a file called JavaScript_Lesson_Object inside this file, I have a function called JavaScriptLssonObject, this function increases an array with objects, (I edited my question, you can see it), then I used reducers (in the file lesson-reducer.js) and called function JavaScriptLessonObject after all this in the file lesson.jsx I got access to this function and as you can see I used ReactHtmlParser my problem is that I cannot use hooks inside the JavaScriptLessonObject function because my function returns an array I wanted to use a hook to to switch to dark or light mode (by the way, I asked a question about the fact that I can not use hooks and did not receive an answer here is the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65728164/react-error-when-using-hook-inside-a-function?noredirect=1#comment116212515_65728164)) In the end, I applied the solutions to use Styled Components inside the lesson.jsx file because I have the ability to access the classes from the JavaScriptLessonObject function I tried to explain the problem as shortly as possible despite the fact that I use google translate I think you got the problem a little

**JavaScript_Lessons_Objects.js**

```
function JavaScriptLessonObject() {
 
    return (
        [
            {
                title: [<p className={jsStyle.title}>Overview</p>],
            },

            {
                titleName: "Indorction",
                heading: 'What is JavaScript ?',
                iconName: faDotCircle,
                data: {
                    description: `              
                    <p class="con"> JavaScript is a dynamic computer programming language.
                  </p>              
                    `
                },
            },
        ]
    );
}

export default JavaScriptLessonObject;
```

**lesson-reducer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import JavaScriptLessonObject from "./Coding_Lessons_Objects/JavaScript_Lessons_Objects";

const ADD_LESSON = "ADD_LESSON";

let initialState = {
    lessonsTitle: JavaScriptLessonObject()
};

export const lessonReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_LESSON:
            return {
                ...state, lessonsTitle: action.lessonsTitle
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const getLessons = (lessonsTitle) => ({
    type: ADD_LESSON, lessonsTitle
});
```

**Lesson.jsx**

```
{
  ReactHtmlParser(this.props.lesson[this.state.indexDescription]["data"]["description"])
}
```

Comment: Hi Synchro. Not sure about what you want, but do you want to use the Style-Component to not style a component and style class instead?

Comment: Hi Carlos. I edited my question, you can read my problem in more detail to understand why I decided to use styled components

Comment: you can add a className normally and work with it <Example className="myClass"/>